# Iphone 802.11 Scan

Tags: iphone, geolocation, position, wifi

I'm developing a system of indoor position use wifi.
however I am having problems with relation to this library of apple.
was once private is now public.

where I use the code.

```
libHandle = dlopen(”/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPConfiguration.bundle/IPConfiguration”, RTLD_LAZY);

apple80211Open = dlsym(libHandle, “Apple80211Open”);
apple80211Bind = dlsym(libHandle, “Apple80211BindToInterface”);
apple80211Close = dlsym(libHandle, “Apple80211Close”);
apple80211Scan = dlsym(libHandle, “Apple80211Scan”);
apple80211Open(&airportHandle);
apple80211Bind(airportHandle, @”en0″);
```

this is code work in IOS6 - in root /Application

to scan the antenna next to the device in case an Iphone.
and thus measure the distance in relation antennas.

put the apple blocked access to this library.
I wonder if there is any other option for this development.
a new library. that perform the same functions.

do not intend to jailbreak
the app works perfect when installed in the root folder of the device.

however intend to publish the source code to the community.
and even launch a test app in apple store.

thanks for the help.
att Eduardo Rabelo
email eduardorabelo@live.com

Comment: I *think* there's a question in here, but it's not very clear Eduardo.  You say the code works in iOS 6, but then you also ask if there's any other options that might work?

Comment: then the code works when the application is installed in the root folder.
and to do this procedure must have the device with JailBreak.
and how I publish the software not only want to restrict who did something "illegal" by the terms of apple.

so was wondering if anyone knows any api alternative.
or a method of using this library in xcode.